# How UWP apps and normal Win programs can talk with each other?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, ipc

Given that UWP, by design, does not support any kind of common Inter Process Communication mechanisms (named pipes, shared memory, ...) what are my options when I want to let existing normal windows program communicate with my UWP app?

Only writing/reading to/from file left, but the UWP documentation is unclear on whether UWP app can access arbitrary files on device.

Comment: For sure you can use local socket communication but as for the rest I think it's currently impossible to achieve.

Comment: In other SO answers people say socket communication on the same machine is blocked, too. :/

Comment: It should work perfectly fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: They say one need to manually disable loopback blocking. Trying this would require to write both server and client apps, so - no. :/

And since recently the word "should" means "it will not work" to me in Microsoft world.

Answer (score 1):

AppServices is the supported way for UWP and Win32 apps to communicate with each other. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).

There are a couple of samples here in the [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples) for Desktop Bridge. Desktop Bridge apps typically make use of this feature, but it can be used by regular Win32 apps as well for communicating with UWP apps (no need to do the Desktop Bridge conversion).